# Import company names from Yahoo Finance

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to import names of companies from Yahoo Finance. There are macros like this on the web, but I want one that imports names exclusively. This is the code but it does not work well:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

Dim WS3 As Worksheet

Set WS3 = Workbooks("Test Name Importer").Worksheets("Sheet 1")

Dim qurl As String
Dim nQuery As Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

qurl = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="

QueryQuote:
    With WS3.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl & " & AAPL &f=" & "n")

        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

    WS3.Select

Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

QuerySheet.Select
Columns("b:j").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I would like advice please.

Comment: How will you store the list of stock symbols that will be used to retrieve the company names?

Comment: I don't want to change our whole idea, but if you can (i.e. "allowed") to use perhaps the main Yahoo site with a Stock Name ([like this](http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=aapl&region=US&lang=en-US)), you could use VBA to parse through the XML to get the name.  Or, do you have to use the .csv?

Comment: I know how to inser the stock symbols, I just want my code to work with one company first.

Comment: I would like to use the csv...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub GetStockNames()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim s$, qurl$

    Const URL = "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=[]&f=n"
    s = "aapl,ko,ge,ibm,msft"
    qurl = Replace(URL, "[]", s)

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        .Columns(1).Clear
        .QueryTables.Add(qurl, [a1]).Refresh False
        .QueryTables(.QueryTables.Count).Delete
    End With

End Sub
```